# When creating multiple instances of an object, treats them like the same object in memory

Tags: ruby

So basically, I'm trying to have different instances of the same object. I'm coming from java, and in java you can just use the new keyword and you're done. I tried "Digit.new" and the last assigned instance of that object changed all instances of that object

I've tried using the "self" keyword, but it just crashes my program.

```
n_one = Digit.new
n_two = Digit.new
n_three = Digit.new
n_four = Digit.new
am_pm = Digit.new

.
.
.
n_three.set_type 3

n_four.set_type 1

class Digit
  @@type = nil

  #This will determine what strings will be returned
  def set_type num
    @@type = num
  end
end
```

What's expected is the type of n_three is 3 and n_four is 1. But n_one, two, three, and four are all 1.

Comment: You gotta show the definition of the class and the `set_type` method. this is not reproducible with this little info

Comment: @maxpleaner I updated it!

Comment: yeah it's like I expected, this is a class-level instance var not a regular instance var. It is shared with all instances. Use `attr_reader :type` and `@type = num` instead

Comment: Sorry i misspoke, it is a class variable not a class-level instance variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill in what max said in comments:

The `@@` sigil defines a class variable (kind of like Java's `static`). Instance variables are identified by the `@` sigil. All of your objects have the same value because they are all sharing the same class variable.

`set_type` looks quite unRubyish in most cases. Java's convention of `getFoo` translates to just `foo` in Ruby, and `setFoo` to `foo=`. As in

```
def foo
  @foo
end

def foo=(value)
  @foo = value
end
```

Furthermore, `obj.foo = bar` is a syntactic sugar for `obj.foo=(bar)` (invoking the function `foo=` with argument `bar`), so the code looks natural (i.e. using a setter looks like assigning a variable).

`attr_accessor :foo` will make both of those methods for you. `attr_reader :foo` and `attr_writer :foo` make just the getter, or just the setter method. Thus, your code can be written as

```
class Digit
  attr_writer :type
end

n_three = Digit.new
n_three.type = 3
```

which is identical to

```
class Digit
  def type=(value)
    @type = value
  end
end

n_three = Digit.new
n_three.type=(3)
```

Of course, if you wish to *read* `n_three.type`, you will need to also define a getter (or replace `attr_writer` with `attr_accessor` in the first snippet). Note that you also do not need to initialize `@type` to `nil`, as it is the default value of an uninitialised instance variable. But you could initialise it in the `initialize` method.

Java conflates constructor and initialiser; in Ruby, the constructor is `::new` (the class method we typically call to create new objects, which you almost never need to override); and the initialiser is `#initialize` (automatically called by the default constructor). You cannot initialise instance variables outside a method like you can in Java. So, the correct way to initialise an instance variable would be:

```
class Digit
  attr_writer :type

  def initialize(type)
    @type = type
  end
end
```

If you defined a setter, you could (and likely should) use `self.type = type` instead of `@type = type`.